# Applying dp for values from 1-10^9

Tags: dynamic-programming

I want to store fibonacci nos from 1-10^9. using dp. How can this be done when the maximum size of array is much less than that.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can't store all the numbers if the maximum allowed array can not store them. How ever you need not store all the values to compute only a single value - you need only 3 variables. Also there is a logarithmic solution for finding `F(n)` - the n-th number of fibonacci.